# Read Formated Text for Java Servlets

Tags: java, sql, servlets

I have a minor problem that sets me back nearly all day and I would like some input on how to solve it.

I am making a servlet for my site and I have a formatted .txt  in the following form:

Name,Surname,Age

for example:

```
mary,jane,23
mark,thomson,25
.
.
.
etc
```

I want somehow to read this txt in order to pass these strings from my .txt to my database, in the corresponding fields.

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: So where's the problem? You know how to write servlets, but not how to read files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will get you started:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String [] split = line.split(",");
    String name= split[0];        
    String surname= split[1];
    Integer age= Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
    //save it to the database
}
//close the reader somewhere
```

Comment: Thanks, so basically I needed  split = line.split(",") didn't know this one existed! Thankies

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();
    Arraylist<String> string_array = new Arraylist<String>();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();

        string_array.add(sb.soString());
    }
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

Subsequently you will separate by comma every element/line in your String Arraylist

```
string_array[i].split(',');
```

and you will proceed to any action you want with the data.